# Why are Calendar.getInstance() and getDate() methods not working as intended? Cannot retrieve Date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have tried retrieving the date for an Android app but for some reason, it is not appearing as intended. I would like the Date to be visible in the application. I've attempted to use the TextView and TextClock types in the XML file (both of which should produce the same result). Still no luck."@+id/current_real_time" does appear in the application and does show the real time (although only the hour and minute). However, "@+id/current_date" does not seem to appear anywhere. Background is Dark Blue. So the android:textColor is not the issue here.

```
''''

<TextClock
   android:id="@+id/current_real_time"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:textSize="16pt"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:layout_marginStart="25dp">
 </TextClock>

''''

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="16pt"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

''''

''''
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activated_ticket_layout);


        //Matching logic to the UI element (add ticket menu)
        ticketToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.addTicketToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(ticketToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add New Tickets");
        ticketToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.plus);

        //Adding and Formatting time
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
        TextClock textClockTime = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.current_real_time);
        textClockTime.setText(currentTime);

        Calendar ticketDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentTicketDate = ticketDate.getDate();

''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know which layout you are using and I assume you are using LinearLayout.

Then, it will be the problem of your TextClock layout because "android:layout_height="match_parent" " pushed the TextView to the bottom, just modify the TextClock layout to use the code below

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/current_real_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16pt"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</TextClock>
```

Also, did you call setText(String) of your TextView? I ask because I cannot see you did from the above code you pasted. Just ignore this question if you did or you can try code below, it will show the full date string(You may need to format it by yourself).

```
    Calendar ticketDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentTicketDate = ticketDate.getTime();

    TextView currentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_date);
    currentDate.setText(currentTicketDate.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. To answer your initial question, yes. I am using LinearLayout. However, when attempting to incorporate the code snippets you have provided, nothing worked. The app did not change.

Comment: Can you show your XML layout? If not, I suggest you remove all other views temporarily to see if the TextView is shown or not. I think there are some other views affecting the layout.

Comment: Src code for the XML file can be found here (posted as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/addTicketToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0066CC"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ticket"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#0066CC">


        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/current_real_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20pt"
            android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextClock>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-100dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20pt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```